# Conditional tags not working, why?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to use a custom template for a woocommerce category, but can't get the conditional to work, do I miss something here? Im trying to change

```
<?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-cans' ); ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php if (is_product_category( 'cans' ) {
woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-cans' );
}else{
woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
} ?>
```

This throws this error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Answer (score 1):

cause missing one more `)`(closing parenthesis) try to replace

```
if (is_product_category( 'cans' ) {
```

to

```
if (is_product_category( 'cans' )) {
```

Also try to read error properly which gives you line number and description what you missing

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (is_product_category( 'cans' ) {
```

to

```
if (is_product_category( 'cans' )) {
```